# Big O-notation related to the Trotter decomposition of matrix exponentials

Tags: linear-algebra, asymptotics, lie-algebras

While reading a paper about "Finding Exponential Product Formulas of Higher Order", I come across the statement that by the well-known trotter decomposition

$1$) $e^{x(A+B)} = e^{xA}e^{xB}+O(x^2)$,

where later the author states that mathematicians put  1) in the form:

$2$) $e^{xA}e^{xB}=e^{x(A+B)+O(x^2)}$.

I am trying to understand why equation $2$ is true. Expanding on both sides gives

$LHS = (I + xA + x^2/2A^2 + \cdots)(I + xB + x^2/2B^2 + \cdots)$=

$= I + x(A+B)+x^2/2(A^2+B^2+2AB) + \cdots$

whereas on the right I'm not sure what it means to take the exponential of a polynomial added to a  matrix $x(A+B)$. I also do not understand why the remaining terms in $LHS$ for power larger than or equal to 3 are absorbed in the big-oh notation.

Moreover I'm not sure what is going on notation-wise with equation 1), as the left hand side is a matrix, while the right is a matrix added to a set of polynomials?

Edit: Additionally, it seems like in the Big O notation, that we are treating matrices as constants (sort of)? I think this might be the heart of my confusion.

Comment: It's just $e^\varepsilon\sim 1+\varepsilon$ for small $\varepsilon$ applied to $\varepsilon=O(x^2)$.

Comment: @Conifold I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Assume $O(x^2)$ is multiplied by the identity matrix. $e^{x(A+B)+O(x^2)}=e^{x(A+B)}e^{O(x^2)}\sim e^{x(A+B)}(1+O(x^2))\sim e^{x(A+B)}+O(x^2)$.

Comment: @Conifold 1 here is the identity matrix?

Comment: Sure. Or you can take it as a number, and treat $O$ as a number or that number times the identity matrix, whichever makes sense.

Comment: @Conifold Ok so this big O expression relates to $x \rightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: The only place where this asymptotic is valid is $x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Conifold ok sorry for the dumb questions lol I'm just very confused about some of the fundamentals here, maybe I will review and get back to this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95944/discussion-between-integratethis-and-conifold).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the right is $$\frac{x^2}2(A+B)^2=\frac{x^2}2(A^2+AB+BA+B^2)$$
which is different because in general $AB\neq BA$.  So you need some $O(x^2)$ correction term.

Comment: I'm curious, does my answer make sense?

Comment: I think i$O(x^2)$ is likely to be another matrix, not $I$, so $x^2M$.  Perhaps $M=BA-AB$ in equation 1) and $M=AB-BA$ in equation 2)

Comment: I think my fundamental confusion here lies in equation 1). The author seems to combine matrices and polynomials(in the Big O notation). I understand that $||e^{x(A+B)}-e^{xA}e^{xB}|| \in O(x^2)$ because of the difference in taylor expansions.

Comment: No, I think that, since it is a matrix equation, there is an implied matrix in $O(x^2)$. Really a string of matrices $x^2M_2+x^3M_3+x^4M_4+\ldots$  The variable $x$ is a scalar.

Comment: Ok that's a good way of putting it! I think I get it now. Thanks.